# Selecting rows with at least 2 consecutive non NA values

Tags: r

I have a following data frame:

```
 df<- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), V1 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("LISINOPRIL", "VALSARTAN"), class = "factor"), 
V3 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("LISINOPRIL", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
V4 = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("LISINOPRIL", 
"VALSARTAN", "NA"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, NA, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("LISINOPRIL", "LOSARTAN", 
"VALSARTAN"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

        > df
  ID   V1         V2         V3         V4         V5
1  1 <NA> LISINOPRIL       <NA>       <NA> LISINOPRIL
2  2 <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> LISINOPRIL
3  3 <NA>  VALSARTAN       <NA> LISINOPRIL   LOSARTAN
4  4 <NA>       <NA>       <NA> LISINOPRIL       <NA>
5  5 <NA>       <NA>       <NA>  VALSARTAN  VALSARTAN
6  6 <NA>       <NA> LISINOPRIL       <NA>   LOSARTAN
```

I would like to create a new column User, which will take value of 1 if at least two consecutive values in this row are not NA. Otherwise it will be zero:

```
         > df
   ID   V1         V2         V3         V4         V5     User
 1  1 <NA> LISINOPRIL       <NA>       <NA> LISINOPRIL       0
 2  2 <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> LISINOPRIL       0
 3  3 <NA>  VALSARTAN       <NA> LISINOPRIL   LOSARTAN       1
 4  4 <NA>       <NA>       <NA> LISINOPRIL       <NA>       0
 5  5 <NA>       <NA>       <NA>  VALSARTAN  VALSARTAN       1
 6  6 <NA>       <NA> LISINOPRIL       <NA>   LOSARTAN       0
```

I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to show us what you've attempted in order to solve the problem.

Comment: @DSSS In some of the columns you have `'NA'` instead of the real `NA`

Comment: @DSSS I noticed that you updated the `df`.  But, still `is.na(df$V4[1])
[1] FALSE`

Comment: Sorry for mistake, akrun, I have edited the data frame.  Honestly, I cannot find a way to approach the problem and would be very grateful for any suggestion, Eric Taylor

Comment: @DSSS Based on your newdataset, it should be all `0`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
df$User <- (apply(!is.na(df[-1]),1,
            function(x) any(with(rle(x), lengths[values])>1)))+0
df
#  ID   V1         V2   V3         V4         V5 User
#1  1 <NA> LISINOPRIL   NA         NA LISINOPRIL    0
#2  2 <NA>       <NA> <NA>       <NA> LISINOPRIL    0
#3  3 <NA>  VALSARTAN <NA> LISINOPRIL   LOSARTAN    1
#4  4 <NA>       <NA> <NA> LISINOPRIL       <NA>    0
#5  5 <NA>       <NA> <NA>  VALSARTAN  VALSARTAN    1
#6  6 <NA>       <NA> <NA>       <NA>   LOSARTAN    0
```

#### Update

Or you could do

```
indx <-!is.na(df[-1])
unname(!!rowSums((indx+cbind(indx[,-1], FALSE))>1))+0
#[1] 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: @DSSS `rle` is one function that is handy for checking consecutive values.

Comment: Thanks again, arkun, I wonder how much I have to practice to be able to write code like this (even at 5-10 times slower rate)

Comment: @DSSS Speed comes with experience.  The key in any programming language is practise.  I would say practise to the point where you become devoted/addicted.